# How to get the browser to store credentials sent with an AJAX request in Authorization header

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, authentication, basic-authentication

Other posts here only show how to send credentials required for a REST backend, this works in the JavaScript part of my application. Problem is that I have to dynamically create "" elements inside my application. Currently, the img src attribute is set by setting application on creation. The src attribute refers to a REST API call delivering the actual image.

A REST AJAX call with auth headers has been successfully sent before. Nevertheless, the browser asks for credentials with a popup again if he tries to access the image referred by the src attribute.

In another post it is mentioned, that there is no possibility to make the browser store the authentication credentials sent by the AJAX request so it can be used for "ordinary" GET request such as the image src attribute later on.

Is there a possibility to load images from a REST API which requires (HTTP Basic Auth-) authentication by  using the img src attribute without forcing the user to enter credentials manually?

Comment: Currently I'm using the workaround to not address the REST Controller directly but using a "Wrapper" function in the frontend (which has a user session with credentials) which forwards the request including the required authentication information to the REST backend.